# Unlock W10M Developer Mode with Windows 7 PC

Tags: windows-10-mobile, windows-7

Is it possible to unlock the Developer Mode on my Nokia Lumia 730(Windows 10 Mobile) with my Windows 7(64bit Pro) PC? I already installed Interop Tools via Device Portal but only signed Appxbundles can be installed there.

Comment: I mean the Developer Registration. I have a License but with all the Tools included in WinPhoneSDK 7.1 dont work. I installed everything they said. Even Zune doesnt recognize my Phone.

Answer (score 1):

Since Windows 10 Mobile you don't need a PC to enable the Developer mode.

1. Open **Settings**
2. Go to **Update & security**
3. Then **For developers**
4. Pick *Sideload apps* or *Developer mode* depending on your needs.

*Enabling device portal allows you to install apps on the phone via a web browser on the PC.*

Windows 7 PCs [can’t run the W10M (UWP) app locally](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn975273.aspx) (only on a remote Windows 10 device). You can’t use the emulators or the simulator in Visual Studio 2015 either.

Comment: I didnt meant "this" Developer Mode, i meant the Developer Registration. I have a License but with all the Tools included in WinPhoneSDK 7.1 dont work. I installed everything they said. Even Zune doesnt recognize my Phone. Its like Windows 10 Mobile is not compatible with Windows 7

Comment: Developer Registration is *not needed* for Windows 10 Mobile. *Zune doesnt work with Windows 10 Mobile* either. When connected to a Windows 10 PC you only have the companion app and you're able to transfer files using *File Explorer* (like music, videos).

Comment: But how can i deploy XAP files with Windows 7?

Comment: Tried the Device Portal? You need to have the phone and PC on the same network and then you can upload the app through your web browser to the phone.

Comment: I know, i tried to install "Interop Unlock 1.7" and it worked. but i still can not install regular .xap or other tools like NativeToastLauncher etc

Comment: xap interop for W10M?

Comment: https://forum.xda-developers.com/windows-10-mobile/windows-10-mobile-apps-and-games/app-interop-tools-versatile-registry-t3445271/

i can edit registry fine, but still can not install regular xaps.

Comment: Found [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JLHqig-WfcM). Might need 3rd party software to do it, think I've done it that way before.

Comment: BTW this is a new question.

Comment: Everytime i start this App Deployer it crashes also WindowsPhonePowerTools crashes. WIthout any error message

Comment: Still, it's off topic so start a new question, please.